# Count user posts by user ID, Post type and Post status

Tags: query

What I am trying to do is modification of this function on codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts Check the title **adding post type support** bottom of the page. The function is:

```
function count_user_posts_by_type($userid, $post_type='post') {
  global $wpdb;
  $where = get_posts_by_author_sql($post_type, TRUE, $userid);
  $count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );
  return apply_filters('get_usernumposts', $count, $userid);
}
```

What I want is to add post status to the function. So, I assume I have to add a WHERE to the query but not sure how to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a quick solution to get the post count any kind of filtering you want

```
function custom_get_user_posts_count($user_id, $args ){ 
    $args['author'] = $user_id;
    $args['fields'] = 'ids';
    $ps = get_posts($args);
    return count($ps);
}
```

Since  this function uses [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) you can filter and use anything that you can with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

So in your case you can use it like this:

```
$count = custom_get_user_posts_count($user_id, array(
    'post_type' =>'post',
    'post_status'=> 'draft'
));
```

Comment: I've checked the wordpress codex and it is not saying anything about author parameters, I know it might not be completed but my query also doesn't work(might be other reasons) but are you sure that get_posts accepts author $user as a parameter?

Comment: This not working and Your Code has mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a custom function I've cooked up, which allows you to query by post type and post status for a particular author. You may need to be careful what arguments you pass as it can include auto-drafts and revisions...

The following is adapted from the `get_posts_by_author_sql`

```
function my_count_posts_by_user($post_author=null,$post_type=array(),$post_status=array()) {
    global $wpdb;

    if(empty($post_author))
        return 0;

    $post_status = (array) $post_status;
    $post_type = (array) $post_type;

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_author = %d AND ", $post_author );

    //Post status
    if(!empty($post_status)){
        $argtype = array_fill(0, count($post_status), '%s');
        $where = "(post_status=".implode( " OR post_status=", $argtype).') AND ';
        $sql .= $wpdb->prepare($where,$post_status);
    }

    //Post type
    if(!empty($post_type)){
        $argtype = array_fill(0, count($post_type), '%s');
        $where = "(post_type=".implode( " OR post_type=", $argtype).') AND ';
        $sql .= $wpdb->prepare($where,$post_type);
    }

    $sql .='1=1';
    $count = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
    return $count;
}
```